# Show that these subsets of R are sequentially compact

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

I have to show that

a) $[2, 2\frac{1}{2}] \cup [3, 3\frac{1}{3}]  \cup [4, 4\frac{1}{4}]  \cup ...$

b){1, 2, 3, ..., $N$} for some $ N \in \mathbb{N} $

are sequentially compact.

I know that in a Metric Space $(M,d)$

M is compact $\Leftrightarrow $ M is sequentially compact $\Leftrightarrow $ M is totally bounded and complete $\Leftrightarrow $ M has the Bolzano-Weierstrass property.

but I am getting confused as to how to use them.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, $(a)$ is not sequentially compact. The sequence $\{2,3,4,\ldots\}$ does not have a convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) This set is not compact in $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric: suppose you have an infinite open cover $(2-\frac{1}{2}, 2 + \frac{2}{3}) \cup (3 - \frac{1}{3}, 3 + \frac{1}{2}) \cup (4 - \frac{1}{4}, 4 + \frac{1}{3}) \cup \dotsc \cup (n - \frac{1}{n}, n + \frac{1}{n-1}) \cup \dotsc$ There is no finite subcover of this cover since the intervals are pairwise disjoint and each interval contains a point from the set.  That means that this set is not compact, thus, not sequentially compact.

b) Take an open cover: $\{1,2,3,\dotsc,N\} \subset \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} C_\alpha$. There is a finite subcover of this set: for each $n = 1$ to $N$ take such index $\alpha_n$ so that $n \in C_{\alpha_n}$. So $\{1,2,3,\dotsc,N\} \subset \bigcup_{n = 1}^N C_{\alpha_n}$.